# Query all siblings of video records according to those on a specific device

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, siblings

I have stored my (almost complete) directories and file names from several storage devices in a MariaDB database. Here I have two tables, DeviceNames and Dirs_and_Files. Table DeviceNames contains two fields. Field F_NR is uniqe which contains the number of a specific storage device. Field D_Name contains the name of the storage device.

Here I store all my storage devices.

```
MariaDB [DevicesPool]> show columns from Devices;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| D_Nr        | varchar(2)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| D_Name      | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

Example records in table Devices:
01 Toshiba-1TB
02 Western-Digital-500GB
03 Seagate-4TB
04 Western-Digital-2TB
...
98 Zyxel-NAS
```

The second table, Dirs_and_Files, contains the following fields: LNR is a uniqe integer value, auto_incremented, the field D_Nr contains the number of the device where the path and the file is stored on.

This D_Nr is a value which should be matched by the D_Nr field in table Devices. The field Filename contains the basename (file name) of stored files. The field Path_and_File contains the whole path and file name then.

```
MariaDB [DevicesPool]> show columns from Dirs_and_Files;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| LNR             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| D_Nr            | varchar(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Filename        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Path_and_File   | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)


Example records for Dirs_and_Files:
01 01 King_Kong.mp4 /Medien/Filme/King_Kong.mp4
02 01 Airport.mp4 /Medien/Filme/Airport.mp4
03 02 Black_Panther.mp4 /Movies/Films/Black Panther.mp4
04 03 Shining.mp4 /Daten/Filme/Shining.mp4
05 03 King_Kong.mp4 /Daten/Filme/King_Kong.mp4
06 04 Alien.mp4 /Daten/Science/Alien.mp4
...
1412 98 Black_Panther.mp4 /home/user/Black_Panther.mp4
```

First, I wanted to have listed only all files (mp4 videos) which appear more than once in the table Dirs_and_Names. This topic is solved as I receive the records from Dirs_and_Files with the numbers 01, 03, 05 and 98. I already have a query to do this.

This is the query command to list just those multiple videos:

```
SELECT d.Path_and_File, p.D_Name 
FROM Dirs_and_Names d 
LEFT JOIN DeviceNames p 
  ON d.D_Nr = p.D_Nr 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT Filename 
    FROM Dirs_and_Names 
    WHERE Filename RLIKE "[.]mp4$" 
    GROUP by Filename 
    HAVING COUNT(Filename) > 1
   ) temp 
  ON d.Filename= temp.Filename 
ORDER BY d.Filename;
```

Now I want to list all the multiple files (mp4 videos) which have siblings on a specific device number (D_Nr) stored in table Dirs_and_Names.
In this case here, I want to have listed "Black_Panther.mp4" and his duplicates which are stored on Device number 98 and 02 also.

The others are not stored on Device "98", so they should be skipped.

How can I query my database for all multiple mp4 video files (Filename) in the table Dirs_and_Names which have a sibling on a specific device number (D_Nr = 98)?

Thank you for patience,

-Linuxfluesterer

Comment: Can you provide sample data to illustrate how *siblings* are denoted?

Comment: siblings are tagged here, where siblings describe a relationship especially in databases. My siblings are mp4 video files, which have the same name and are stored on different locations (paths and/or devices and path.
I have edited my complete question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding an `INNER JOIN` on another `Dirs_and_Names` to filter on specific device:

```sql
SELECT d.Path_and_File, p.D_Name 
FROM Dirs_and_Names d 
LEFT JOIN DeviceNames p 
  ON d.D_Nr = p.D_Nr 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT Filename 
    FROM Dirs_and_Names 
    WHERE Filename RLIKE "[.]mp4$" 
    GROUP by Filename 
    HAVING COUNT(Filename) > 1
   ) agg 
  ON d.Filename= agg.Filename 
INNER JOIN Dirs_and_Names d2
  ON agg.Filename = d2.Filename
  AND d2.D_Nr = 98
ORDER BY d.Filename;
```

Comment: Puuh, what an action about this topic. But finally you, Parfait, has sent a very good solution, which works, and which I can adapt to future queries.
Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!